# How do I access information from this unfamiliar data structure via Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm using `Fog` to access a cloud environment at Terremark. When I pull down our organizational data it returns a data structure that, while I know it should be straight forward, confuses me.

Using `irb` I initialize the connection and then request the data using `conn.organizations` and display it with `awesome_print`. It returns:

```
[
    [0]   <Fog::Compute::Ecloud::Organization
    href="/cloudapi/ecloud/organizations/#######",
    name="****************************** (***-###-###)",
    type="application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.organization",
    other_links=[{:href=>"/cloudapi/ecloud/admin/organizations/#######", :name=>"****************************** (***-###-###)", :type=>"application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.admin.organization", :rel=>"alternate"}, {:href=>"/cloudapi/ecloud/environments/organizations/#######", :type=>"application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.environment; type=collection", :rel=>"down"}, {:href=>"/cloudapi/ecloud/devicetags/organizations/#######", :type=>"application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.deviceTag; type=collection", :rel=>"down"}, {:href=>"/cloudapi/ecloud/alerts/organizations/#######", :type=>"application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.alertLog", :rel=>"down"}]
  >
]
```

So it is returning an array with a singular element. That element is comprised of another data structure surrounded by `<` and `>`. But I'm not certain if that's accurate because there also appears to be another array containing a hash embedded within that structure.

My issue is that I need to extract the value represented by the `#######` but I don't know how to access any of the sections of the output which contain that value.

What am I looking at as far as the data structure is concerned and how do I go about access the data contained within?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `Fog::Compute::Ecloud::Organization` object and the documentation of that class should tell you what methods are available. Or you can just ask the object itself, by calling `Object#methods`.

Comment: You are correct that calling `Object#methods` will display applicable methods. Unfortunately, I don't see one which expresses the value I'm looking for. In fact, one which I though might get me close is `Object.href`. This, unfortunately, does not containing anything. It is `nil`. `Object.display`, however, will print out the object's contents in the original format.